# Test Magento 1.6.2.0 Direct Post Authorize.net payment method with test credit cards

Tags: magento-1.6

Has anyone tried testing the Authorize.net Direct Post Method with test credit cards using Magento 1.6.2.0?

I tried using the `4111111111111111` Visa test credit cards, switching the Authorize.net account from test `mode:on` and test `mode:off`.These transactions are captured on Authorize.net account but the checkout page in Magento does not redirect to Success page, instead i get an error message

An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. This transaction has been approved. It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.

Could someone elaborate on how to test credit card transactions in Magento 1.6.2.0 using Direct Post Authorize.net payment method?

Answer (score 0):

The Direct Post Method requires Authorize.net open a communication to your server (essentially, the customer sends information directly to Authorize.Net including the credit card number, expiration date, etc... as well as a URL that Authorize.Net uses to communicate to your server).  Because of this, your test site will need to be publicly accessible (i.e. firewall open, with a domain name registered and pointed to the site).